Integrating $\int 8\sin^3x\cos x\;dx$. Why is my solution with the substitution $u=\cos x$ wrong?
Why can I not do this?
\begin{align*}
\int 8\sin^3x\cos xdx=8\int (1-\cos^2x)\sin x\cos x\ dx
\end{align*}
Let $u=\cos x$, $-du = \sin xdx$:
\begin{align*}
-8\int (1-u^2)\ u\ du 
=-8\int (u-u^3)\ du 
=-4\cos^2x+2\cos^4x+C
\end{align*}
The book and online is telling me this would be the answer to this specific integral, however, if I am doing a $u$-sub this way with $u=\cos x$, what am I doing wrong specifically that I have to use u-sub to let $u=\sin x$ and $du=\cos xdx$. I understand there way is faster, however I did not see it initially and just did this instead, but why is it incorrect?
\begin{align*}
2\sin^4x+C
\end{align*}
I'm working on a 1st order linear D.E. which is:
\begin{align*}
y\ \cos\ x= \int8\ \sin^3x\ \cos\ x\ dx
\end{align*}
My final answer of the D.E. should be: 
\begin{align*}
y=(1/\cos x)(2\sin^4x+C)
\end{align*}

Hint: $2\sin^4 x-2\cos^4 x+4\cos^2x=2(\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x)(\sin^2 x+\cos^2x)+4\cos^2 x=2$

https://www.integral-calculator.com/ has a nice feature for checking whether your answer and another answer are actually the same.

next time please write \sin and \cos instead of sin and cos

Thanks, I will try to keep the \sin and \cos in mind for my next question, appreciate the integral calculator link too, thats clutch.

It's obvious enough what your point of confusion is, but it's very hard to figure out which parts of the question are your work, which are the book's solution, which are your questions about the apparent difference between the two, and which are background information that isn't directly involved in solving the integral. For example, you say you "just did this" -- what is "this"? Is it something that you wrote before, or is it the formula you write immediately afterward? Three previous uses of "this" are also difficult to assign. Clear writing is important.

Both answers are correct. Or, they are equivalent.

You really got the same answer.
$$2\cos^4x -4\cos^2 x \ = \ $$
$$2(1-\sin^2 x)^2 -4(1-\sin^2 x) \ = $$
$$-2-4\sin^2 x +2\sin^4 x + 4\sin^2 x \ = $$
$$2 \sin^4 x + C,$$ which is in your book's answer.

Attempting to summarize your question, you solved the integral one way, and the book showed a different way. The two solutions are
$$ \int 8\sin^3x\cos x \,\mathrm dx \stackrel?= -4\cos^2x+2\cos^4x+C_1, $$
$$ \int 8\sin^3x\cos x \,\mathrm dx \stackrel?= 2\sin^4x+C_2. $$
Notice that
\begin{align}
 2\sin^4 x &= 2(\sin^2 x)^2 \\
&= 2(1 - \cos^2 x)^2 \\
&= 2(1 - 2\cos^2 x + \cos^4 x) \\
&= -4\cos^2 x + 2\cos^4 x + 2.
\end{align}
That is, $2\sin^4x$ and $-4\cos^2 x + 2\cos^4 x$ differ by only a constant and either one (plus a constant) is a correct solution of the integral.
